# Binding blocks of a Section to another Section

Tags: binding, flowdocument

I have a `FlowDocument` with several `Paragraps` and `Tables`, this `FlowDocument` should repeat itself presenting the exact copy after the middle of the page. I'm using 2 `Sections` to achieve that.

To make thing easy, I'm trying to bind a section to another:

```
<Section x:Name="MainSection" Padding="10">
    <!-- Lots of things -->
</Section>

<Section Padding="10" Blocks="{Binding ElementName=MainSection, Path=Blocks}"/>
```

But unfortunately, `Blocks` does not have an accessible setter. How could I replicate the contents without having to duplicate my XAML?

PS: I'm not using C# code to create the page visual, only to fill in the paragraphs and tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom control that inherits from `Section` and create a bindable property and instead of binding it to `Blocks` you bind it to the new property. Inside the custom control, handle the property changed for that new property and add the value to the actual `Blocks` property.